# Passing back info between delegates on ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, tableview

I need to pass back an NSMutableArray of photos between a CameraSessionView; how store the photos taken from camera on an NSMutableArray, and a TableViewController how uploads this photos to DropBox. I'm using delegates and protocols, but all the ways I tried... fail.
Anyone can help me. I think Im doing some little thing wrong.
I show you some code:

CameraSessionView.h

```
@class CameraSessionView;
@protocol CameraSessionViewDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(void)uploadPhotosFromCamera:(NSMutableArray*)photos;
@end

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CameraSessionViewDelegate> delegado;
```

CameraSessionView.m

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* images;

- (void)onTapOkButton{

    NSLog(@"Save photos");

    if([self.delegado respondsToSelector:@selector(uploadPhotosFromCamera:)])
    [self.delegado uploadPhotosFromCamera:_images];

    [self onTapDismissButton];
}
```

PhotosTableViewController.h

```
@interface PhotosTableViewController : UITableViewController <CameraSessionViewDelegate>
```

PhotosTableViewController.m

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CameraSessionView *camera;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
_camera = [CameraSessionView new];
[_camera setDelegado:self];
}
-(void)uploadPhotosFromCamera:(NSMutableArray*)photos
{
    NSLog(@"UPFC");
    for(int x=0; x < [photos count];x++)
    {
        NSLog(@"UPFC...");

        UIImage *foto = [photos objectAtIndex:x];

         if (foto.size.height > 1000 || foto.size.width > 1000)
             foto = [self imageWithImage:foto scaledToScale:0.15f];

         DBMetadata* datos = [TablaSubidas addFile:pathElemento];
         NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
         NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(foto, 1.0);
         [fileManager createFileAtPath:[self photoPath:datos] contents:data attributes:nil];
         [elementosTabla insertObject:datos atIndex:0];
    }

    [self sincFotos];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Only wants that when I press OK button the photos send back to PhotosTableViewController where it would be uploaded to dropbox.

self.delegado on onTapOKButton is always nil.

Looks easy but I cant run it. 
I'm so grateful if anyone could help me or recommend me any tutorial...

Thanks!!

Comment: You have not implemented in PhotosTableViewContoller the 
-(void)uploadPhotosFromCamera:(NSMutableArray*)photos;

I think that is pretty much what was is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CameraSessionView` instance will be released from memory as soon as viewDidLoad ends. You need to store it in a property in `PhotosTableViewController` so that it is retained.

Your delegate should also be defined as weak, e.g.

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) id< CameraSessionViewDelegate >delegado;
```

Then in your implementation of PhotosTableViewController, you'll need to implement the `-(void)uploadPhotosFromCamera:(NSMutableArray*)photos;` method.

Also as this method is defined as `@optional`, you should check if the delegate responds to it before calling it.

```
   if([self.delegado respondsToSelector:@selector(uploadPhotosFromCamera:]){
        [self.delegado uploadPhotosFromCamera:_images];
   }
```

This will prevent the app from crashing if the delegate method isn't implemented.

Comment: -uploadPhotosFromCamera method was already implemented, I forget to paste it. 
This IF (...respondsToSelector... ) is never done... self.delegado is nil

Comment: At what stage do you add the CameraSessionView to the screen?

Comment: I have a tableview, and in when I press on the first cell I cant select the way to add photos to the tableview, from the gallery or from the camera (CameraSessionView) this may help you https://www.dropbox.com/s/yp7lblacj2ujohw/2015-10-19%2013.30.06.png?dl=0

Comment: Yes but where in code, can you post that? Seems your delegate is being deallocated after you set it before you can call back.

Comment: When I push the first cell, I call an actionsheet and depends of selections perform a segue to camerasessionview...

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. So, you can implement this Directly. Hope, you will get success. Oh! first check without camera activity. Just pass simple **array** of **string**  to test the **delegate**

/............*****************

CameraSessionView.h file

/............*****************

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class CameraSessionView;

@protocol CameraSessionViewDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void)uploadPhotosFromCamera:(NSMutableArray*)photos;

@end

@interface CameraSessionView : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,weak) id< CameraSessionViewDelegate >delegado;

@end
```

/............*****************

CameraSessionView.m file

/............*****************

```
#import "CameraSessionView.h"

@interface CameraSessionView ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* images;
@end

@implementation CameraSessionView


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(onTapOkButton)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)onTapOkButton{

NSLog(@"Save photos");
_images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[_images addObject:@"_images1"];
[_images addObject:@"_images2"];

//NSLog(@"from del:%@",_images);

if([self.delegado respondsToSelector:@selector(uploadPhotosFromCamera:)])
    [self.delegado uploadPhotosFromCamera:_images];

[self onTapDismissButton];
}
-(void)onTapDismissButton{
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
}

@end
```

/............*****************

DetailViewController.m file

/.........********

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "CameraSessionView.h"


@interface DetailViewController ()<CameraSessionViewDelegate>

@end


@implementation DetailViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
CameraSessionView *Camara= [[CameraSessionView alloc]initWithNibName:@"CameraSessionView" bundle:nil];
[Camara setDelegado:self];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:Camara animated:YES];
}


-(void)uploadPhotosFromCamera:(NSMutableArray*)photos{
NSLog(@"success:%@",photos);
}
@end
```

Comment: I did the changes that Jeff tell me and looks better... but still without calling the delegado method

Comment: did you implement "-(void)uploadPhotosFromCamera:(NSMutableArray*)photos{
    NSLog(@"success:%@",photos);
}"

Comment: method in PhotosTableViewController.m file?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to pass data from B View Controller To A view Controller

1. Create protocol in B View Controller as

   ```
   @protocol BViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
   -(void)didclickonSubmit:(NSArray*)selected_array;
   @end
   ```
2. Create an id, so that you can assign any class as its delegate class.

   ```
   @property (weak,nonatomic) id<BViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
   ```
3. Call this method in B View Controller on submit button or wherever required.

   ```
   if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didclickonSubmit:)])
   {
   [self.delegate didclickonSubmit:myarray];
   }
   ```
4. Create an object of B View Controller in View Controller A and assign A as delegate of B

   ```
   BViewController *b = [[BViewController alloc]init];
   b.delegate=self;
   ```
5. Implement required protocol methods of B in A and access the array

   ```
     -(void)didclickonSubmit:(NSArray*)array
     {              
        NSArray *myarray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:array];
     }
   ```

   now you can use myarray,as u like it..

hit link for sample project
https://www.dropbox.com/s/002om8efpy6fout/passDataToPreviousContoller.zip
Hope it helps..

****EDITED****
 u can for sure assign tableViewController as delegate of UIView class.

```
@protocol BView <NSObject>
-(void) didclickonSubmit:(NSArray*) selected_array;
@end
@interface BView : UIView
@property (weak,nonatomic) id<BView> delegate;
@end  

  in A i.e. your tableViewController create an object of B and assign your tableview controller as delegate of B .


BView *b=[[BView alloc]init];                                                                                            
b.delegate=self;
```

Happy Coding..:)

Comment: I think there is an issue... in my proyect... ViewControllerA is TableViewController and ViewControllerB is an UIView... would be any problem?

Comment: It shouldn't be the problem. u can for sure assign tableViewController as delegate of UIView class. I have updated my ans.

Comment: Your code wrks for me , have u tried with debugger.. put a debugger on where you have implemented delegate method of B in tableViewController. Does the debugger reaches there after clicking submit button..??? If it does then problem must be in the path where you have saved the images.