# Why is my prepareForSegue method not being called?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

When I press the back button in this navigation controller, I want to send the state of the switches to variables in a different View Controller. However, the prepareForSegue method is not being called. How do I fix this?

[image]

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    print("here")
    let secondViewController:ViewController2 = segue.destination as! ViewController2

    if undoSwitch.isOn {
        secondViewController.undoControls[0] = true
    }
    else {
     secondViewController.undoControls[0] = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The back button is different from `segue`. If you want to reload the `undoSwitch` when going back from the current view controller. One of the ways is to use a static global variable. Something like

```
class AppVar {
    static var controlState = true
}
```

Update your AppVar.controlState where you need and add this

```
if AppVar.controlState {
    secondViewController.undoControls[0] = true
}
else {
     secondViewController.undoControls[0] = false
}
```

to `viewWillAppear` of the `ViewController2` as the `ViewController2` was retained and stored in stack. When you navigate back to it, the `viewWillAppear` will be called.

Comment: I don't think I can access the state of the switches because they are not in secondViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`, add an action to it, and do whatever you want.
Or use `https://github.com/onegray/UIViewController-BackButtonHandler`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB you can pass data using prepare for segue method or instantiating ViewControllerB storyboard id and access its properties and pass data.

If you want to do vice-versa i.e. passing data back from ViewControllerB to ViewControllerA, you can use various patterns. Delegation , Notification , Kvo or using NSUserDefaults.

In your case Delegation Pattern will be best. Assign ViewController2 as delegate of your current class. And pass data(in your case control state) using protocols of your current class. Implement the protocol in  ViewController2 and access control state of your switches and do accordingly. You can refer my previous [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44896038/settings-page-to-add-or-subtract-different-image-arrays-coding-with-swift-and-x/44897002#44897002) on this topic.Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211074/passing-back-info-between-delegates-on-objectivec/33213308#33213308) for my detailed ans in Objective-C.
Hope it helps. Hapy Coding!!

Comment: I think I have a better solution. I just moved the variable undoControls outside of the class. Now, I can easily access it wherever I need it since it is public. Is there any reason why this would not be a good idea?